# boxplot shows number of data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(11, 1),
                  columns=['Col1'])
df['X'] = pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A',
                     'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B','B'])
boxplot = df.boxplot(by='X')
```

I want to the `boxplot` shows the number of 'A' and 'B' (for 'A' is 5 and for 'b' is 6) in the figure . What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
box_plot = sns.boxplot(x = 'X', y = 'Col1' , data = df)

medians = df.groupby(['X'])['Col1'].median()
counts = (df.groupby(['X'])['Col1'].count())

vertical_offset = df['Col1'].median() * 0.05 # offset from median for display

for xtick in box_plot.get_xticks():
    box_plot.text(xtick,medians[xtick] + vertical_offset,counts[xtick], 
            horizontalalignment='center',size='medium',color='w',weight='bold')
```

[image]